# Making sure move constructor gets called

Tags: c++, c++11, move, move-semantics

I have the following simplified code example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class ShouldBeMovedWhenSwapped
{
public:
//  ShouldBeMovedWhenSwapped() = default;
//  ShouldBeMovedWhenSwapped(ShouldBeMovedWhenSwapped&&) = default;
//  ShouldBeMovedWhenSwapped(const ShouldBeMovedWhenSwapped&) = default;
//  ShouldBeMovedWhenSwapped& operator=(ShouldBeMovedWhenSwapped&&) = default;

    struct MoveTester
    {
        MoveTester() {}
        MoveTester(const MoveTester&) { cout << "tester copied " << endl; }
        MoveTester(MoveTester&&) { cout << "tester moved " << endl; }
        MoveTester& operator=(MoveTester) { cout << "tester emplaced" << endl; return *this; } // must be declared if move declared
    };

    MoveTester tester;
};

int main()
{
    ShouldBeMovedWhenSwapped a;
    ShouldBeMovedWhenSwapped b;
    std::swap(a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using MinGW, while running 'gcc --version' i get gcc 4.7.2

**EDIT**:
for the first question see the comments in the question. It appears to be a bug in gcc.

The output of the code depends on which constructors are commented out. But i don't understand why the differences occur. **What is the reason behind each output?**

```
// Everything commented out
tester moved 
tester copied <---- why not moved?
tester emplaced
tester copied <---- why not moved?
tester emplaced

// Nothing commented out
tester moved
tester moved
tester emplaced
tester moved
tester emplaced

// Move constructor commented out
tester copied
tester moved
tester emplaced
tester moved
tester emplaced
```

For my second question (which was why i started this test) - Let's say i have a real case with a large vector instead of the class MoveTester, **how can i be sure the vector is moved instead of being copied** in such cases?

Comment: What compiler are you using? For me [everything works as expected](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e88c684591aeed6)

Comment: Most probably you're using an old GCC compiler, my guess version 4.7.x

Comment: @AntonSavin Thanks! that was a quick way to see that it depends on the compiler. I added the information in the question.

Comment: As for my second question?

Comment: @user1708860: Declaring move assignment `T& operator=(T&&)` removes the auto generation of move-constructor `T(T&&)`, so copy is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first part of the problem is an outdated compiler, but there's another one: you declared `MoveTester::operator=` in suboptimal way - it takes its argument by value, so a copy/move constructor is invoked one extra time. Try this version of `MoveTester`:

```
struct MoveTester
{
    MoveTester() {}
    MoveTester(const MoveTester&) { cout << "tester copied " << endl; }
    MoveTester(MoveTester&&) { cout << "tester moved " << endl; }
    MoveTester& operator=(const MoveTester&) { cout << "tester copy assignment" << endl; return *this; } // must be declared if move declared
    MoveTester& operator=(MoveTester&&) { cout << "tester move assignment" << endl; return *this; } // must be declared if move declared
};
```

I'm getting [the following output](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f38209718f63e10b):

```
tester moved 
tester move assignment
tester move assignment
```

Perhaps you'll get something similar even with GCC 4.7.

---

Regarding your second question, the move constructor of `std::vector` is guaranteed by standard to have constant time complexity. The question is whether the compiler obeys the standard. I believe the only way to make sure is to debug or to profile your code.

Comment: I declared it like that because of the 'copy and swap idiom' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom

But i indeed get that exact output if i change the operator

Comment: Well, now i'm even more confused, this seems to be the output i wanted. According to the linked question, this version should have resulted in an optimal code...

Comment: @user1708860 there's no contradiction here. Your version indeed would employ copy&swap idiom, so in `operator=` you would just swap contents - not much work. Just update the compiler and you'll be able to use the original version.

Comment: @user1708860 now you understand why the copy-and-swap idiom is usually sub-optimal in performance terms.  Its benefits are ease of implementation, and ease of strong exception safety.